# How do I recover a deleted or overwritten bash

Tags: bash, login, data-recovery

I have overwritten `/bin/bash` with another executable I wanted to `mv` to the `/bin`

Now I have login loop in normal usr login as well as in the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> terminal which u can access before login.

Recovery mode starts but after the OK checks brings me to the login screen and not the real recover interface.

secure boot is switched of in BIOS.

Is there any other way to recover from deleted bash.

Comment: You shouldn't have logged out. You could have used the default shell, /bin/dash, to run apt-get and install bash again

Answer (score 2):

#### If you don't have access to a live disk:

While booting the system hold the <kbd>shift</kbd> so grub menu appears, press <kbd>e</kbd> to edit the default menu entry, find the line started with "Linux" and add `init=/bin/sh` at the end of that line, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>.

Now you will be dropped into a `dash`shell, run:

```
chsh username -s /bin/sh
```

reboot your system, now you can login successfully and you'll have a `dash` shell, reinstall your bash:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bash
```

then change your default shell to bash:

```
sudo chsh username -s /bin/bash
```

#### When you still have a running terminal:

As a bones, if you ever removed a program which has a running instance you can easily recover it from "procfs", in case of `bash` if you had a terminal running bash you could fix the bash by running:

```
sudo cp /proc/$$/exe /bin/bash
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Boot a live Ubuntu from USB/DVD and copy its `/bin/bash` over that of your Ubuntu installation to get a mostly functional system.
2. Boot your Ubuntu installation and run

   ```
   sudo apt-get install --reinstall bash
   ```

   to restore all Bash files the way they're supposed to be.